# Run a bash script to overwrite variables used by Git

Tags: git, macos, terminal, macos-monterey

I put the following two variables inside `.bashrc` on my MacOS Monterrey machine:

```
$ export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Wed Feb 16 14:00 2037 -0600"
$ export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Wed Feb 16 14:00 2037 -0600"
```

In the real case the dates are dynamically populated, only the time zone is fixed.

This works as intended when I manually enter the commands into terminal.

It fails inside the .bashrc file after a systerm reboot. I suspect Git is overwriting these two variables during startup, which nullifies the intent of putting this in `.bashrc`

Is there an alternate way to load these commands after a delay, so that they are set after Git initializes?

Comment: On Monterey you should be using `zsh`.

Comment: Git won't override them itself (except for things like `git filter-branch` or `--date` options to `git commit` or the like), but as @matt suggests, if you're on MacOS Monterey you may have zsh as your shell, rather than bash, and zsh reads zshrc files rather than bashrc files.